# How to cast rails model integer status to string name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a status on one of the models, and want to make it right. Here is a current code version:

```
  self::TEST_NONE = 0
  self::TEST_PENDING = 1
  self::TEST_DONE = 2

  def self.test_status_name name
    case name
      when self::TEST_NONE
        'None'
      when self::TEST_PENDING
        'Pending'
      when self::TEST_DONE
        'Done'
      else
        'None'
    end
  end
```

And in the view

```
<%= Device::test_status_name @device.test_status %>
```

Which works in general but feels wrong. I want to implement something like a default to_s method for test_status. Additional class could work (not sure how to implement it right), but I don't need and want AR-backed model there, just several constant statuses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not something like

```
class Device
  TEST_STATUSES = %w{ None Pending Done }

  def test_status_name
    test_status ? TEST_STATUSES[test_status] : 'None'
  end
end

<%= @device.test_status_name %>
```